# No Route Error but have the route in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

Here is my routes file:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  resources :users do
    post 'update_and_sign_in', :on => :member
  end
```

Here is the output from rake routes:

```
update_and_sign_in_user POST   /users/:id/update_and_sign_in(.:format) users#update_and_sign_in
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
```

Here is the controller:

```
  def update_and_sign_in
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     if  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
       redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You have successfully signed up"
     else
       render 'get_email' 
     end
  end
```

Here is the form:

```
=form_for(@user,:url => update_and_sign_in_user,:method => "put", :html => {:class => 'well'}) do |f|
```

I get this error and I can't figure out why or how to fix it:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update_and_sign_in", :controller=>"users"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route is a POST but your method in the form is PUT.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: Which controller is :

```
    def update_and_sign_in
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You have successfully signed up"
      else
       render 'get_email' 
      end
    end
```

on? UsersController or Users::OmniauthCallbacksController ?